# How do separate a six digit numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have a six digit number, so i want to get the first two digit and the last four digit and store it in a variable.

```
int sixDigit = 102020;
```

I want something like this:

```
int firstTwo = 10;
int lastFour = 2020;
```

Thank you!

Comment: ... Do some math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sixDigit = 102020;
int firstTwo = sixDigit / 10000;
int lastFour = sixDigit % 10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

or maybe you want this:

```
int sixDigit = 102020;
String sixDigitString = String.valueOf(sixDigit);
int firstTwo = Integer.valueOf(sixDigitString.substring(0,2));
int lastFour = Integer.valueOf(sixDigitString.substring(2,6));
```